# How can I avoid TLE on SPOJ with this prime number generator program?

Tags: c, primes

This is the Prime Number generator program on SPOJ. I am facing the dreaded "Time Limit Exceeded" error. How can I overcome it? 
This is the link to the problem:-
https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

What could be the reason? I am still a beginner and I searched on net and it's telling me to use some algorithms, but right now I don't know any algorithms.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime(int a,int b)
{
    int y=0;
    for (int i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        for (int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            int x=i%j;
            if (x==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                y++;
            }
        }
        if (y==i-2)
        {
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
        y=0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int test;
    int arr1[11],arr2[11];
    char space[11];
    scanf("%d",&test);

    if (test>10)
    {
        goto end;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<test;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%c%d",&arr1[i],&space[i],&arr2[i]);
        if (arr1[i]>=1 && arr1[i]<=arr2[i] && arr2[i]<=1000000000 && arr2[i]-arr1[i]<=100000 && space[i]==' ')
        {
            prime(arr1[i],arr2[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
end:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are numerous other questions about primes and how to speed up the checking. You don't need to search up to N-1; up to and including `ceil(sqrt(N))` is sufficient. If N is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other is not smaller than √N). After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd numbers. If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1. Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in the thousands, let alone much bigger.

Comment: Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3. If the range to be searched is big enough (the maximum value is large enough), building a Sieve of Eratosthenes (or even more advanced techniques — such as Sieve of Atkin) for the primes up to the square root of the maximum and then testing only the 'known to be prime' possible factors can be beneficial. Eventually, deterministic evaluation of 'is it a prime' becomes too slow and you resort to probabilistic prime detection such as the Miller-Rabin test. See Wikipedia on [Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test).

Comment: don't use sieve of Atkin if you can avoid it. it's impractical.

Comment: One trick is to build your own set of test data (and correct results) which covers the full range of inputs specified. Then you'll know if you are anywhere close to the time limit. I solve some of the SPOJ questions, and for the non-trivial ones, it can take a considerable time whittling it down. If you are prepared to do this, it will be worth the effort. But asking other people for a solution (apart from figuring out what any mistake might be) would be a hollow victory. Especially with primes, there is plenty of material out there! The *real* challenge here is to solve it in the time limit.

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't work for this problem the constraint are too big and would cause both memory and time limit to exceed.

Comment: @executable Sorry. Got rid of the comment

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to check if a number if prime. It's complexity is O(sqrt(N)).
The O(N*sqrt(N)) proposed solution passes all test cases as n-m <= 100000.

```
 bool checkprime(int x){
        if(x==1)
            return false;
        if(x<=3)
            return true;
        for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(x);i++){
            if(x%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Some pseudo code to call and check if a number is prime.

```
for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
    if(checkprime(i))
        cout<<i<<endl;
    else
        continue;
 }
```

However the **Segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes** method works much faster and is a better method to answer all the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to be quadratic, which will time out for large numbers. To make it more efficient, you can try a different method such as the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-sieve-of-eratosthenes-to-generate-prime-numbers-between-given-range)

Comment: Sieve of Eratosthenes doesn't work for this large constraint. Both memory and time limits will exceed. Segmented sieve is required.